# Не будет ли ошибкой поставить для объекта много колайдеров? или лучше сделать через EdgeColider?

Tags: unity3d

Не будет ли ошибкой поставить для объекта много колайдеров? или лучше сделать через EdgeColider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если мы говорим о том, что лучше - добавить 5 компонентов `BoxCollider2D` или 1 компонент `EdgeColider2D`, то лучше держдать кол-во компонентов по минимуму, т.е. 1 компонент лучше, чем 5.

В общем случае:
Если объект будет динамическим, и нужна фигура с закрытыми границами - `BoxCollider2D`.
Если объект будет статическим, и проверять нужно просто границу - `EdgeColider2D`.

Но в любом случае, об ошибках тут речи не идет, делайте так, как вам быстрее и удобнее, очень маловероятно что выбор между `BoxCollider2D` или `EdgeColider2D` даст вам ощутимый прирост производительности, или окажется узким местом производительности.